# Удалить выборочные строки из файла

Tags: python, файлы, строки

Доброе время суток.

Подскажите как в Python3 можно выполнить удаление первой, второй и последней строк в файле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f=open(file).readlines()
for i in [0,0,-1]:
    f.pop(i)
with open(file,'w') as F:
    F.writelines(f)
```